# HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL. (Java rest api with jersey)

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey

im following one of the online tutorials for making rest api in java. I work in `Eclipse 4.5.2`.  When i enter `http://localhost:7001/ds2/api/v1/status` i got mentioned in a title error. I included `Jersey 1.19`. Im using `Oracle WebLogic Server 12c R2 (12.2.1).` Starting page(index) works fine, but anything i would enter after /api/ gives me the same error.

My `V1_status.java` class:

```
package ds2.status;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.*;

@Path("/v1/status")
public class V1_status {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String returnTitle() {
        return "<p>Java Web Service</p>";
    }
}
```

My `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>ds2</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>ds2</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  </web-app>
```

`weblogic.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.8/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <wls:weblogic-version>12.2.1</wls:weblogic-version>
    <wls:context-root>ds2</wls:context-root>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

What can cause it or maybe how can i investigate by myslef whats wrong?

Comment: Could be a couple of things.  Your resource could not be getting picked up by Jersey, your URLs configuration might not be exactly as you want.  I often end up putting a breakpoint in ServletContainer's service method and working from there.  What version of Jersey are you using?  The parameter names changed in Jersey 2 from what you are using.  See http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/Help-needed-with-JAX-RS-2-0-and-web-xml-td7580825.html

Comment: Thanx, i eventually switched to netBeans where after long investigations i found that this IDE after 6.5 adds a /webresources/ in ULR. Maybe in Eclipse there was something simular