# HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL Rest-full WS on WL 12.2.1

Tags: java, rest, weblogic12c, jersey-1.0

I have developed a Rest-full WS which runs successfully on tomcat.

The application deploys succesfully in Weblogic 12.2.1 without any exceptions. However, on hitting the URI, I face "HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL Rest-full WS" in response.

This happens for POST methods as well and while generating wadl also.

Below is the Rest WS implemation class

```
@POST
@Path("/activateService")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public Response crunchifyREST**(JsonObject model**, @Context 
HttpServletRequest request) {

}

    @GET
@Path("/verify")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response verifyRESTService(InputStream incomingData) {
    String result = "GMPPMediatorTIMService Successfully started..";

    // return HTTP response 200 in case of success
    return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();
}
```

web.xml :-

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>FacadeHandsetTimpay</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.trivnet.mediator.tim.services</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FacadeHandsetTimpay</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I am using URI as :- http://localhost:8070/FacadeHandsetTimpay/api/getLastTimPayTransactions

I checked below links , however I could find any help 
[HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL. (Java rest api with jersey)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36372876/http-method-get-is-not-supported-by-this-url-java-rest-api-with-jersey)

Comment: You are using uri /getLastTimPayTransactions but you have provided code for /activateService and /verify. Please Clarify.

Comment: can you post the url for GET and POST request ?

Comment: URI for /activateService http://localhost:8070/FacadeHandsetTimpay/api/activateService

URI for /verify 
http://localhost:8070/FacadeHandsetTimpay/api/verify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution . 12.2.1, WebLogic Server Jersey 1.x server-side APIs are no longer supported. You should use the corresponding standard JAX-RS 2.0 or Jersey 2.x APIs instead. The Jersey 1.x client API is deprecated. It is recommended that you update your RESTful client applications to use the JAX-RS 2.0 client APIs at your earliest convenience.

So , remove these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
   <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
   <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
   <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.0-m12</version>
```

And use these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
   <version>2.17</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
   <version>2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

And also change web.xml as follows:-

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>FacadeHandsetTimpay</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.trivnet.mediator.tim.services</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FacadeHandsetTimpay</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Source:-
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/wls/RESTF/intro-restful-service.htm#RESTF109